# wxPython binding of EVT_SET_FOCUS to combobox causing unwanted behavior

Tags: wxpython

When I bind the EVT_SET_FOCUS to my combo box my function does what it should.  However Then when I try to clck on the combobox (a drop down variety) to change the value the drop down no longer occurs.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to retain the original functionality while still binding my new functionality?

Answer (score 4):

Call Skip() at the end of your function so the event continues propagating:

```
def OnFocus(self, evt):
    # do some event handling stuff
    evt.Skip()
```

If that's not the problem, post your code.